# How do I correctly get the value of 'ⅻ' (and other similar non-alphabetical characters) and store it in a string?

Tags: java, unicode

Given a character that is not a standard alphabet character, such as `'ⅻ'`, I'm having problems converting it to a string and retaining it's value.  For example If I have:

```
String myStr = "ⅻⅾ℡ℬ";
Character myChar = myStr.charAt(0);
```

Then `System.out.println('ⅻ' == myChar);` returns true, whereas `System.out.println("ⅻ" == Character.toString(myChar));` returns  false.

Thus my question effectively is how do I correctly get the value of `'ⅻ'` and store it in a string?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't compare `String`s in java with `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these conditions return true:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String myStr = "ⅻⅾ℡ℬ";
        Character myChar = myStr.charAt(0); 

        System.out.println('ⅻ' == myChar);
        System.out.println("ⅻ".equals(Character.toString(myChar))); 
    }
}
```

Comment: so `(Character.toString(myChar)` does actually contain "ⅻ"?

Comment: @Anya yes, `.equals()` tests for value equality. Similarly, if you called `System.out.println(Character.toString(myChar));`, the result would be `ⅻ`.